# Angularjs individual process execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Would like to check I have a simple web service resource query function like this

```
//Get country lists
$scope.getCountry = function(){
    $http({
        method  : 'GET',
        url     : cdnLinks('country'),
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.countries = data;
    }).error(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};

//Get profile 
$scope.getProfile = function(profile_id, select){
     var formatJSON = {
            profile_id: profile_id,
            select: select,
        };
    var json = JSON.stringify(formatJSON);
    var urlsafe = exEncrypt(json);
    ProfileService.profileActions.query({payload:urlsafe}).$promise.then(function(datas){
        $scope.uProfile = datas[0];
        document.querySelector('title').innerHTML = $scope.uProfile.username;
    });  
};

//Initialize update sequence
$scope.initUpdate = function(profile_id, select){
    $scope.getCountry();
    $scope.getProfile(profile_id, select);
}
```

So what the code does is upon a user click on the "Update" button, it will fire `ng-click="initUpdate(param1, param2)"` function which will then load all and display the necessary information to a user. This function works perfectly but there is one problem. Because that the `getCountry()` usually returns a larger file size [~3 - 3.5kb, load time ~260++ms server dependent] compare to plain `getProfile()` [~1 - 2kb, load time ~200++ms server dependent], what the code does is the profile will be displayed before the country list is being loaded which in the UI page ended up with some empty field not filled in.

So what i does initially is by applying a timeout to `getProfile()` like this

```
$scope.initUpdate = function(profile_id, select){
    $scope.getCountry();
    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.getProfile(profile_id, select);
    }, 200);
}
```

which works fine for a moment but again i cannot specifically define the amount of time to be delayed since the loading part is server dependent.

I would like to check if there is any approach that i can use / implement such that i want

1. All the necessary resources to be loaded and **COMPLETED** (`getCountry()`, `getInterest()`, `getABCDEFG()` and some other gets...)
2. only the `getProfile()` function is being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use promises (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to do this. Add $q dependency to your controller, and then, us a promise in getCountry() & initUpdate().

It will wait for getCountry() request to be finished before going on. Moreover, if you want to add other requests, you can use $q.all() to wait for several requests to be completed before displaying the profile.

```
$scope.initUpdate = function(profile_id, select){
    $scope.getCountry().then(
        function(){
            $scope.getProfile(profile_id, select);
        }
    );
}

$scope.getCountry = function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method  : 'GET',
        url     : cdnLinks('country'),
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.countries = data;
        deferred.resolve();
    }).error(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        deferred.reject();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

(Note: You might be able to improve the code by returning $http promise directly)

Comment: I totally agree on the fact that $http already returns a promise, either with success / error or then and that its not optimal. I'm just writing clear code. My example is correct and anyone can understand / improve it.

$q is indeed for async JS. Period. It has nothing to do with long loading or mobile use. Just use it if you want async code, which is now nearly a must-have on every good JS app.

You should read the $q page. The subtitle clearly says "A service that helps you run functions asynchronously, and use their return values (or exceptions) when they are done processing."

Comment: At this moment noKid 's way of doing it solved my problem. I will let it run while also try on @Okazari 's solution since it require me to redesign certain part of the module. But either ways both solution does solve my problem... The only problem is Oka's approach would require some major changes in my other dependent modules... Cheers...

Comment: @KennyYap Yup i knew that, that was just to keep you informed :) (about ui-router) The first part should also work tough.

Comment: "On a standard angular app you don't need to run code asynchronously". I cannot agree with that. JS apps today should use asynchronous code as much as they can to offer the best UI / UX experience. The fact that you use resolve on ui-router is the proof. There are just many ways of doing async, and $q is one of them to use.

Answer (score 2):

You could just display some loaders on the parts that shouldn't show.

Create a boolean var to hide/show the loader if the call is pending or not.

If you want to load some things before the view load you can give a look at [ui-router and its resolve properties](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve).

You could also return the $http call in your functions so that you can handle it the way you want. (Chaining them for exemple).

```
//Get country lists
$scope.getCountry = function(){
    return $http({
        method  : 'GET',
        url     : cdnLinks('country'),
    });
};

//Get profile 
$scope.getProfile = function(profile_id, select){
     var formatJSON = {
            profile_id: profile_id,
            select: select,
        };
    var json = JSON.stringify(formatJSON);
    var urlsafe = exEncrypt(json);
    return ProfileService.profileActions.query({payload:urlsafe}).$promise  
};

//Initialize update sequence
$scope.initUpdate = function(profile_id, select){
    $scope.getCountry().success(function(data) {
        $scope.countries = data;
        $scope.getProfile(profile_id, select).then(function(datas){
           $scope.uProfile = datas[0];
           document.querySelector('title').innerHTML = $scope.uProfile.username;
        });
    }).error(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

This should work, but if you get the idea you can adapt it to your ideas and uses.

Hope it helped, if you have anymore question (specially about ui-router) feel free to ask.

EDIT :

Note that usually $http calls are not set up into a controller but into a service.

Here is an exemple of a state (from ui-router) definition with resolves :

```
$stateProvider
  .state('mystate', {
    url: "myroute"
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    controller: "mystateController",
    resolve : {
        countries : function($http){
                           return $http({
                           method  : 'GET',
                           url     : cdnLinks('country'),
                        });
                    }
    }
  })
```

You will be able to inject the resolve param into your controller :

```
app.controller('mystateController', function(countries) {
  //Here goes your countries.
  console.log(countries);
});
```